COPERNICUS/DEM/GLO30 in Google Earth Engine
I'm having an issue with Google Earth Engine. I'm attempting to download .csv files of COPERNICUS/DEM/GLO30 elevation data at specific latitude & longitude points (n=266). The code below works for 205 of the points, but does not extract any data for the remaining 61 points. I have tried to run the code with only these 61 points, and the data appears to extract (i.e., no errors pop up), but when I open the resulting .csv file it is blank. I have mapped out the points overlayed on the elevation layer and they clearly overlap with areas with elevation data (e.g., points located in Nevada). Anyone have insight on how to fix this issue? Here is an example of what the point files look like:
Bird.ID Latitude Longitude region
202301559_a 42.50446 -100.5332 Center

And here is my Google Earth Engine code:
// Downloading COPERNICUS/DEM/GLO30 elevation data at my lat/lon pts

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Upload lat/lon pts
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Context: To make it easier for GEE to process all of the pts, I manually split the pts into smaller subsets (sorted by region) before uploading to GEE and then processed each subset separately in this script.

var p1 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-sendy/assets/wy_pts');

var p2 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-sendy/assets/west_pts');

var p3 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-sendy/assets/southcan_pts');

var p4 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-sendy/assets/northeast_pts');

var p5 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-sendy/assets/northwest_pts');

var p6 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-sendy/assets/midwest_pts');

var p7 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-sendy/assets/east_pts');

var p8 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-sendy/assets/center_pts');

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Verify that everything has the same spatial projection
// ---------------------------------------------------------
var elevationProjection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/DEM/GLO30').first().projection();
var SO2Projection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_SO2').first().projection();
var NO2Projection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2').first().projection();
var pointProjection = p1.first().geometry().projection();

print('Elevation Projection:', elevationProjection);
print('SO2 Projection:', SO2Projection);
print('NO2 Projection:', NO2Projection);
print('Points Projection:', pointProjection);

// all datasets have same spatial projection

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Define point geometries based on "Latitude" and "Longitude" columns
// ---------------------------------------------------------

var p1 = p1.map(function(feature) {
  var lat = ee.Number(feature.get('Latitude'));  // Retrieve latitude
  var lon = ee.Number(feature.get('Longitude')); // Retrieve longitude
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]);      // Create point geometry
  return feature.setGeometry(geom);              // Set geometry for each feature
});

var p2 = p2.map(function(feature) {
  var lat = ee.Number(feature.get('Latitude'));  
  var lon = ee.Number(feature.get('Longitude')); 
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]);      
  return feature.setGeometry(geom);              
});

var p3 = p3.map(function(feature) {
  var lat = ee.Number(feature.get('Latitude'));  
  var lon = ee.Number(feature.get('Longitude')); 
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]);     
  return feature.setGeometry(geom);              
});

var p4 = p4.map(function(feature) {
  var lat = ee.Number(feature.get('Latitude'));  
  var lon = ee.Number(feature.get('Longitude')); 
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]);     
  return feature.setGeometry(geom);              
});

var p5 = p5.map(function(feature) {
  var lat = ee.Number(feature.get('Latitude'));  
  var lon = ee.Number(feature.get('Longitude')); 
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]);     
  return feature.setGeometry(geom);              
});

var p6 = p6.map(function(feature) {
  var lat = ee.Number(feature.get('Latitude'));  
  var lon = ee.Number(feature.get('Longitude')); 
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]);     
  return feature.setGeometry(geom);              
});

var p7 = p7.map(function(feature) {
  var lat = ee.Number(feature.get('Latitude'));  
  var lon = ee.Number(feature.get('Longitude')); 
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]);     
  return feature.setGeometry(geom);              
});

var p8 = p8.map(function(feature) {
  var lat = ee.Number(feature.get('Latitude'));  
  var lon = ee.Number(feature.get('Longitude')); 
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]);     
  return feature.setGeometry(geom);              
});

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// Load in variable of interest (elevation)
// -----------------------------------------------------------
var elevation = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/DEM/GLO30')
  .mosaic(); // merges overlapping tiles in case any pts lay on tile boundaries
  
// -----------------------------------------------------------
// Sample the data at the points
// -----------------------------------------------------------
var elev1 = elevation.sampleRegions({
  collection: p1,      
  scale: 30,               
  geometries: true // Keep geometries to include lat/lon in output
});

var elev2 = elevation.sampleRegions({
  collection: p2,      
  scale: 30,               
  geometries: true 
});

var elev3 = elevation.sampleRegions({
  collection: p3,      
  scale: 30,               
  geometries: true 
});

var elev4 = elevation.sampleRegions({
  collection: p4,      
  scale: 30,               
  geometries: true 
});

var elev5 = elevation.sampleRegions({
  collection: p5,      
  scale: 30,               
  geometries: true 
});

var elev6 = elevation.sampleRegions({
  collection: p6,      
  scale: 30,               
  geometries: true 
});

var elev7 = elevation.sampleRegions({
  collection: p7,      
  scale: 30,               
  geometries: true 
});

var elev8 = elevation.sampleRegions({
  collection: p8,      
  scale: 30,               
  geometries: true 
});

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// Export result as CSV's to Google Drive folder
// -----------------------------------------------------------
// - Elevation
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: elev1,
    description: '2024_1119_elevation_1',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    folder: 'Google Earth Engine'
  });
  
    Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: elev2,
    description: '2024_1119_elevation_2',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    folder: 'Google Earth Engine'
  });
  
    Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: elev3,
    description: '2024_1119_elevation_3',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    folder: 'Google Earth Engine'
  });
  
    Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: elev4,
    description: '2024_1119_elevation_4',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    folder: 'Google Earth Engine'
  });
  
    Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: elev5,
    description: '2024_1119_elevation_5',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    folder: 'Google Earth Engine'
  });
  
    Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: elev6,
    description: '2024_1119_elevation_6',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    folder: 'Google Earth Engine'
  });
  
    Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: elev7,
    description: '2024_1119_elevation_7',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    folder: 'Google Earth Engine'
  });
 
     Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: elev8,
    description: '2024_1119_elevation_8',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    folder: 'Google Earth Engine'
  });


Share your tables.
